# How can I access more than 1 element from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, storage, local

I know it's probably silly question but I am newbie and can't handle this.

Here is what I have:

```
    <div class="form-group">
  <label for="category">Choose category:</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="category">
    <option>food</option>
    <option>drinks</option>
    <option>bills</option>
    <option>others</option>
  </select>
  <textarea type="text" id="price" class="input-inline"></textarea>
</div>
  <textarea type="text" id="name" class="input-inline"></textarea>
  <div id="DisplayItem"></div>
  <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="SaveItem()" style="width:120px;margin:auto">Save it</a>
  <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="DisplayItem()" style="width:150px;margin:auto">Display it</a>

</form>
```

and script:

```
           function SaveItem() {
    localStorage.setItem("category", jQuery("#category").val());
}

function DisplayItem() {
    jQuery('#DisplayItem').text(localStorage.getItem("category"));


}
```

With this code I will get only the category but I would like to get values from all fields.
For example I would like to have result like:
Your category is 'C', name is 'N' and price 'P'. Where C, N and P stands for values from formular.
How can I achieve it with one function?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Best option is to manage all related data as an object.

```
function SaveItem() {
    var item = {
        category: jQuery("#category").val(),
        name: jQuery("#name").val(),
        price: jQuery("#price").val()
    };
    localStorage.setItem("item", JSON.stringify(item)); //JSON.stringify() transforma el objeto en un string en formato JSON para poder guardarlo
}

function DisplayItem() {
    var item = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("item")); //JSON.parse() transforma un string en formato JSON un objeto
    var output = "Category: " + item.category + " - Price: " + item.price + " - Name: " + item.name;
    jQuery('#DisplayItem').text(output);

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to add a few items in this way? For example I would like to save three items and in the end as a result show total price for all of them?

Comment: Sure, just follow the same concept. Instead adding item to local storage you can add items to an array, and then save the items array in local storage. Then for showing you will get back those items and you can iterate over them to show each one.

Answer (score 1):

Local Storage can store JavaScript objects, so say you have two categories.

You could build an object like:

```
localStorage.setItem('categories', {
   category1: $("#category").val(), category2: $("#category-two").val()
});
```

Notice I swapped out `jQuery` for the dollar notation `$` since it's just an alias to the jQuery object, it does exactly the same but it's shorthand.

You could store an array

```
var categories = [];
categories.push($('#category-one').val());
categories.push($('#category-two').val());
localStorage.setItem('categories', categories);
```

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do but you can store many items under one key within the Local Storage API by storing JavaScript objects.